# does running a synchronous function inside an async function make the function still run synchronously or will it make it run asynchronously? node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, fs, synchronous

specfically when using fs.copyFilesync()  and running it in an async function, will fs.copyFilesync() still run synchronously or will it run in an asynchronous manner like the fs.copyfile() function. My issue is that i have an async function and i need to copy the file first inside the async function and make sure it has finished copying the file before it executes the rest of the code inside the async function, so in this case is it better to use fs.copyfile() inside the async function or fs.copyFilesync() inside the async function?

```js
const fs = require("fs");
async function hi(){
fs.copyFilesync()
//or
//fs.copyFile()

/*rest of code inside this async function must run only after the file has been fully copied, so i assume it is better to use fs.copyFilesync inside the async function or does the async function make fs.copyFilesync() run asynchrnously? */
}
```

Comment: It will not magically turn async. Use an async version, maybe from `fs/promises` so you can await it.

Comment: so wont fs.copyFilesync() be good enough since it will block the execution of the rest of the code inside the async function until it has finished copying the file or am i wrong, compared to using fs.copyfile()?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.